# Calling action with Redux-thunk not working

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux, axios, redux-thunk

I am trying to use redux with react to do an api call to GET some data. When calling the function in my component, the reducer is not seeing the action.type and the function is returning a Promise resolved. I've not used redux-thunk before. The code as I have I feel should work but I am having difficulty finding the error.  Here is the code.

Index.js

```
const store = createStore(rootReducer, composeWithDevTools(applyMiddleware(thunkMiddleware, devToolsEnhancer)));

ReactDOM.render(
  <Provider store={store}>
    <BrowserRouter>
      <App />
    </BrowserRouter>
  </Provider>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

Action

```
import axios from 'axios';

export const GET_ALL_CASES = "GET_ALL_CASES";


const getCasesSuccess = (cases) => {
    return {
        type: GET_ALL_CASES,
        cases
    }
};

export const getAllCases = () => {
    return (dispatch) => {
        axios.get('https://corona.lmao.ninja/countries?sort=country')
        .then(response => {
            dispatch(getCasesSuccess(response.cases))
        })
        .catch(error => {
            throw(error)
        })
    }
}
```

Reducer

```
import { GET_ALL_CASES } from '../actions';

const initialState = {
    allCases: []
}

const rootReducer = (state = initialState, action) => {
    switch (action.type) {
        case GET_ALL_CASES:
            return { ...state, allCases: [...action.cases]}
        default:
            return state;
    }
}

export default rootReducer;
```

Component

```
class Second extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {  }
    }

    componentDidMount = () => {
        getAllCases()
    }


    render() { 
        return ( 
            <div>
                {this.props.data[0]}
            </div>
         );
    }
}

const mapStateToProps = (state) => (
    {
      data: state.allCases
    }
  )

  const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => {
    return {
      getAllCases: () => dispatch(getAllCases())
    }
  }

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(Second);
```

When calling the function, if I change it to this.props.getAllCases(), I get this error.

```
Unhandled Rejection (Error): Expected the reducer to be a function.
▶ 5 stack frames were collapsed.
getAllCases
C:/Users/Owner/Desktop/corona-app/src/containers/second.js:33
  30 | 
  31 | const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => {
  32 |   return {
> 33 |     getAllCases: () => dispatch(getAllCases())
     | ^  34 |   }
  35 | }
  36 |
```

Comment: Did you try ```this.props.getAllCases()```?

Comment: @AliTorki When I change it to this.props, I get this error. ```Unhandled Rejection (Error): Expected the reducer to be a function.
▶ 5 stack frames were collapsed.
getAllCases
C:/Users/Owner/Desktop/corona-app/src/containers/second.js:33
  30 | 
  31 | const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => {
  32 |   return {
> 33 |     getAllCases: () => dispatch(getAllCases())
     | ^  34 |   }
  35 | }
  36 | ```

Comment: Provide your store configuration code

Comment: @AliTorki it is already provided in my index.js

Comment: the second arg of createStore is an initial state object which you didn't apply.
```const store = createStore(rootReducer, {},  composeWithDevTools(applyMiddleware(thunkMiddleware, devToolsEnhancer)));
```

Comment: @AliTorki even after doing this, I'm met with the same error

Comment: @AliTorki ```const store = createStore(rootReducer, {}, composeWithDevTools(applyMiddleware(thunkMiddleware, devToolsEnhancer)));```

Comment: This createStore config is wrong and you should apply the initial object(even empty) to the second arg of this function.

Comment: I have an initial state within the rootreducer.

Comment: Now, you get the same error?

Comment: What if you use `mapDispatchToProps` like this `const mapDispatchToProps = { 
getAllCases }`? It wraps in dispatch automatically

Answer (score 1):

There are different ways to use dipatchMapToProps or how ever its named.

But don't think too much on it as I do, use the easiest one

- as an object

```js
const dispatchToProps = {
  fun1,
  enter,
  code,
  herefun2
}
```

- as function

```js
const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => {
  return {
    // dispatching plain actions
    increment: () => dispatch({ type: 'INCREMENT' }),
    decrement: () => dispatch({ type: 'DECREMENT' }),
    reset: () => dispatch({ type: 'RESET' })
  }
```

````js
    import React from "react";
    import {connect} from "react-redux";
    import {getAllCases} from "path-of-the-file";

    class Second extends React.Component {
        constructor(props) {
            super(props);
            this.state = {
                someState: ""
            }
        }

        componentDidMount () {
           const { getAllCases } this.props;

           getAllCases()
        }


        render() { 

          const {data} = this.props;

            return ( 
                <div>
                    {data[0]}
                </div>
             );
        }
    }

    const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
       return {
          data: state.allCases
        }
      }

      const mapDispatchToProps = { getAllCases }

    export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(Second);
    ```
````